# Nested for loop filtering inner loop based on outer loop and appending dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I am trying to build a dataframe that combines individual dataframes of county-level high school enrollment projections generated in a for loop.

I can do this for a single county, based on this SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72450593/for-loop-calculate-values-and-append-to-initial-record-in-pandas). It works great. My goal now is to do a nested for loop that would take multiple county FIPS codes, filter the inner loop on that, and generate an 11-row dataframe that would then be appended to a master dataframe. For three counties, for example, the final dataframe would be 33 rows.

But I haven't been able to get it right. I've tried to model on this SO [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64774519/python-append-dataframe-generated-in-nested-loops).

This is my starting dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"year": ['2020_21', '2020_21','2020_21'],
    "county_fips" : ['06019','06021','06023'] , 
    "grade11" : [5000,2000,2000],
    "grade12": [5200,2200,2200],
    "grade11_chg": [1.01,1.02,1.03],
    "grade11_12_ratio": [0.9,0.8,0.87]})
df
```

This is my code with the nested loops. My intent is to run through the county codes in the outer loop and the projection year calculations in the inner loop.

```
projection_years=['2021_22','2022_23','2023_24','2024_25','2025_26','2026_27','2027_28','2028_29','2029_30','2030_31']

for i in df['county_fips'].unique():
    print(i)
    grade11_change=df.iloc[0]['grade11_chg']
    grade11_12_ratio=df.iloc[0]['grade11_12_ratio']
    full_name=[]
        
    for year in projection_years:
        #print(year)
        df_select=df[df['county_fips']==i]
        lr = df_select.iloc[-1]
        row = {}
        row['year'] = year
        row['county_fips'] = i
        row = {}
        row['grade11'] = int(lr['grade11'] * grade11_change)
        row['grade12'] = int(lr['grade11'] * grade11_12_ratio)
        df_select = df_select.append([row])
        full_name.append(df_select)

df_final=pd.concat(full_name)
df_final=df_final[['year','county_fips','grade11','grade12']]
   
print('Finished processing')
```

But I end up with NaN values and repeating years. Below shows my desired output (I built this in Excel and the numbers reflect rounding. (Update - this corrects the original df_final_goal .)

```
df_final_goal=pd.DataFrame({'year': {0: '2020_21',  1: '2021_22',  2: '2022_23',  3: '2023_24',  4: '2024_25',  5: '2025_26',
  6: '2026_27',  7: '2027_28',  8: '2028_29',  9: '2029_30',  10: '2030_31',  11: '2020_21',  12: '2021_22',  13: '2022_23',
  14: '2023_24',  15: '2024_25',  16: '2025_26',  17: '2026_27',  18: '2027_28',  19: '2028_29',  20: '2029_30',  21: '2030_31',
  22: '2020_21',  23: '2021_22',  24: '2022_23',  25: '2023_24',  26: '2024_25',  27: '2025_26',  28: '2026_27',  29: '2027_28',
  30: '2028_29',  31: '2029_30',  32: '2030_31'},
 'county_fips': {0: '06019',  1: '06019',  2: '06019',  3: '06019',  4: '06019',  5: '06019',  6: '06019',  7: '06019',  8: '06019',
  9: '06019',  10: '06019',  11: '06021',  12: '06021',  13: '06021',  14: '06021',  15: '06021',  16: '06021',  17: '06021',  18: '06021',
  19: '06021',  20: '06021',  21: '06021',  22: '06023',  23: '06023',  24: '06023',  25: '06023',  26: '06023',  27: '06023',
  28: '06023',  29: '06023',  30: '06023',  31: '06023',  32: '06023'},
'grade11': {0: 5000,  1: 5050,  2: 5101,  3: 5152,  4: 5203,  5: 5255,  6: 5308,  7: 5361,  8: 5414,  9: 5468, 10: 5523,
  11: 2000,  12: 2040,  13: 2081,  14: 2122,  15: 2165,  16: 2208,  17: 2252,  18: 2297,  19: 2343,  20: 2390,  21: 2438,
  22: 2000,  23: 2060,  24: 2122,  25: 2185,  26: 2251,  27: 2319,  28: 2388,  29: 2460,  30: 2534,  31: 2610,  32: 2688},
 'grade12': {0: 5200,  1: 4500,  2: 4545,  3: 4590,  4: 4636,  5: 4683,  6: 4730,  7: 4777,  8: 4825,  9: 4873,  10: 4922,
  11: 2200,  12: 1600,  13: 1632,  14: 1665,  15: 1698,  16: 1732,  17: 1767,  18: 1802,  19: 1838,  20: 1875,  21: 1912,
  22: 2200,  23: 1740,  24: 1792,  25: 1846,  26: 1901,  27: 1958,  28: 2017,  29: 2078,  30: 2140,  31: 2204,  32: 2270}})
```

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: can you update the code in order to make it reproducible? the initial (test) dataframe lacks columns `county_fips` (is it `county_code`?), `grade11_chg` or `grade11_12_ratio` columns. These 3 columns are used in the latter piece of code. Also note that the `projection_years` values are not all present in test dataframe

Comment: I see now why the projection_years should not be the dataframe, they represent the rows to be added.

Comment: My apologies. I had an earlier df version in there. It's updated now.

Comment: in your `df_final_goal` you have `grade11` equaling values that don't match the output of your for-loop. E.g. `5000 * 1.01 != 6079` and `5200 * 0.9 != 5417`. In fact the first row per `[(year, county_fips)]` group should be equal to your original `df` but they aren't. Is something off with the final? Or the original?

Comment: You are correct @IanThompson . I botched doing the df_final_goal numbers in Excel. I updated the post. Thank you.

Comment: noticed you have rounded values in your final output instead of using `int` which floors the floats. Which do you want? e.g. -> `df_final_goal.loc[2, "grade11"] == 5101` instead of `5100` (original calculation would have been `int(5050 * 1.01) == 5100`)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I prefer to have the final output reflect the original calculation - int(5050 * 1.01) == 5100 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are some bugs in the code, this code seems to produce the result you expect (the final dataframe is currently not consistent with the initial one):

```py
projection_years = ['2021_22','2022_23','2023_24','2024_25','2025_26','2026_27','2027_28','2028_29','2029_30','2030_31']

full_name = []
for i in df['county_fips'].unique():
    print(i)
    df_select = df[df['county_fips']==i]
    grade11_change = df_select.iloc[0]['grade11_chg']
    grade11_12_ratio = df_select.iloc[0]['grade11_12_ratio']
        
    for year in projection_years:
        #print(year)
        lr = df_select.iloc[-1]
        row = {}
        row['year'] = year
        row['county_fips'] = i
        row['grade11'] = int(lr['grade11'] * grade11_change)
        row['grade12'] = int(lr['grade11'] * grade11_12_ratio)
        df_select = df_select.append([row])
    full_name.append(df_select)

df_final = pd.concat(full_name)
df_final = df_final[['year','county_fips','grade11','grade12']].reset_index()
   
print('Finished processing')
```

fixes:

- `full_name` initialized before the outer loop
- do not redefine `df_select` in the inner loop
- `row` was initialized twice inside the inner loop
- `full_name.append` moved outside of the inner loop and after it
- added `reset_index()` to `df_final` (mostly cosmetic)
- (**edit**) grade change variables (`grade11_change` and `grade11_12_ratio`) are now computed from `df_select` last row (and not `df`)

the final result (`print(df_final.to_markdown())`) with the above code is:

|  | index | year | county_fips | grade11 | grade12 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 2020_21 | 06019 | 5000 | 5200 |
| 1 | 0 | 2021_22 | 06019 | 5050 | 4500 |
| 2 | 0 | 2022_23 | 06019 | 5100 | 4545 |
| 3 | 0 | 2023_24 | 06019 | 5151 | 4590 |
| 4 | 0 | 2024_25 | 06019 | 5202 | 4635 |
| 5 | 0 | 2025_26 | 06019 | 5254 | 4681 |
| 6 | 0 | 2026_27 | 06019 | 5306 | 4728 |
| 7 | 0 | 2027_28 | 06019 | 5359 | 4775 |
| 8 | 0 | 2028_29 | 06019 | 5412 | 4823 |
| 9 | 0 | 2029_30 | 06019 | 5466 | 4870 |
| 10 | 0 | 2030_31 | 06019 | 5520 | 4919 |
| 11 | 1 | 2020_21 | 06021 | 2000 | 2200 |
| 12 | 0 | 2021_22 | 06021 | 2040 | 1600 |
| 13 | 0 | 2022_23 | 06021 | 2080 | 1632 |
| 14 | 0 | 2023_24 | 06021 | 2121 | 1664 |
| 15 | 0 | 2024_25 | 06021 | 2163 | 1696 |
| 16 | 0 | 2025_26 | 06021 | 2206 | 1730 |
| 17 | 0 | 2026_27 | 06021 | 2250 | 1764 |
| 18 | 0 | 2027_28 | 06021 | 2295 | 1800 |
| 19 | 0 | 2028_29 | 06021 | 2340 | 1836 |
| 20 | 0 | 2029_30 | 06021 | 2386 | 1872 |
| 21 | 0 | 2030_31 | 06021 | 2433 | 1908 |
| 22 | 2 | 2020_21 | 06023 | 2000 | 2200 |
| 23 | 0 | 2021_22 | 06023 | 2060 | 1740 |
| 24 | 0 | 2022_23 | 06023 | 2121 | 1792 |
| 25 | 0 | 2023_24 | 06023 | 2184 | 1845 |
| 26 | 0 | 2024_25 | 06023 | 2249 | 1900 |
| 27 | 0 | 2025_26 | 06023 | 2316 | 1956 |
| 28 | 0 | 2026_27 | 06023 | 2385 | 2014 |
| 29 | 0 | 2027_28 | 06023 | 2456 | 2074 |
| 30 | 0 | 2028_29 | 06023 | 2529 | 2136 |
| 31 | 0 | 2029_30 | 06023 | 2604 | 2200 |
| 32 | 0 | 2030_31 | 06023 | 2682 | 2265 |

**note**: edited to address the comments

Comment: For the first county_fips - 0619 - the above code gives values that closely match what I get doing the math in Excel. Numbers for the other two counties are not what I expect. For county_fips 06021 in year 2030-31, for example, I get 2438 for grade11 and 1912 for grade12 in Excel. The above code returns 2205 and 1965.

Comment: @JamesMiller I get 2433 for grade 11, year 2030-31, county 06021. If you do all the calculations without converting to int, you get 2437.9888... Maybe Excel is rounding at the end instead of throughout the series?

Comment: Right, thanks @IanThompson . Both  2433 or ~2437 are quite a bit different from 2205. But I think I see what might be going on -- it appears that the grade11_change and grade11_12_ratio variables are not updating in the outer for loop. In df, each county has different values for those variables. But it seems the outer loop is taking the values for the first county (06019), and using those to generate all three counties' projections in the inner loop. My goal is for grade11_change and grade11_12_ratio variables to update on each loop.

Comment: @JamesMiller That can be solved by moving the `grade11_change` and `grade11_12_ratio` assignments into the second loop. But as a word of advice, I'd avoid using for-loops as much as possible when working with `pandas`. It has a lot of features that help get away from looping, and they tend to be a lot faster due to vectorization.

Comment: right, there was another issue in the code, see the edited code with a new fix. Now I am getting results consistent with what is reported by @IanThompson.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a helper function for calculating `grade11` helps make this a bit easier.

```
import pandas as pd


def expand_grade11(
    grade11: int,
    grade11_chg: float,
    len_projection_years: int
) -> list:
    """
    Calculate `grade11` values based on current
    `grade11`, `grade11_chg`, and number of
    `projection_years`.
    """

    list_of_vals = []
    while len(list_of_vals) < len_projection_years:
        grade11 = int(grade11 * grade11_chg)
        list_of_vals.append(grade11)

    return list_of_vals


# initial info
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "year": ['2020_21', '2020_21','2020_21'],
    "county_fips": ['06019','06021','06023'] , 
    "grade11": [5000,2000,2000],
    "grade12": [5200,2200,2200],
    "grade11_chg": [1.01,1.02,1.03],
    "grade11_12_ratio": [0.9,0.8,0.87]
})
projection_years = ['2021_22','2022_23','2023_24','2024_25','2025_26','2026_27','2027_28','2028_29','2029_30','2030_31']

# converting to pd.MultiIndex
prods_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product((df.county_fips.unique(), projection_years), names=["county_fips", "year"])

# setting index for future grouping/joining
df.set_index(["county_fips", "year"], inplace=True)

# calculate grade11
final = df.groupby([
    "county_fips",
    "year",
]).apply(lambda x: expand_grade11(x.grade11, x.grade11_chg, len(projection_years)))
final = final.explode()
final.index = prods_index
final = final.to_frame("grade11")

# concat with original df to get other columns
final = pd.concat([
    df, final
])
final.sort_index(level=["county_fips", "year"], inplace=True)
final.grade11_12_ratio.ffill(inplace=True)

# calculate grade12
grade12 = final.groupby([
    "county_fips"
]).apply(lambda x: x["grade11"] * x["grade11_12_ratio"])
grade12 = grade12.groupby("county_fips").shift(1)
grade12 = grade12.droplevel(0)

# put it all together
final.grade12.fillna(grade12, inplace=True)
final = final[["grade11", "grade12"]]
final = final.astype(int)
final.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

Comment: It's possible that I'll be adding other grades to my script. For this approach, am I correct in thinking that would involve defining functions and adding #calculate grade code blocks for the additional grades? Thanks.

Comment: that depends on their dependencies. I updated my script to only have one function (`grade11`) because it is the only value dependent on itself. `grade12` depends on `grade11` and `grade11_12_ratio` so it's transformation can be done directly.

Comment: I'm going to work through this solution. I think it will help me become more experienced with functions.